# How do I apply an operation using .map lambda expression using a different value from a list each time?

Tags: java, lambda

Forgive me for the title im not sure how to articulate this problem as a question.

Anyway, my questions is this.Take this function,

```
function(object o, String a) { 
    stuff; 
    return new object o;
}
```

How would I make it so that when using the `.map` lambda expression I could apply this operation to each variable in the stream, in order, so that the I could call the function like this `.map(l -> function(l, stringArraylist))` so that the function applies for the string in the equivalent position in its arraylist, as L is in its own stream.

Comment: question is pretty much unclear. try explaining silmply the things you want to do. Are you trying to apply a function to each element from a list ? or something else ?

Answer (score 2):

> the function applies for the string in the equivalent position in its arraylist, as L is in its own stream

This is a bit vague, but it appears you want to apply your `function` on pairs of elements belonging to two collections (the first collection is of some unspecified type - let's call it `SomeClass` - and the other is an `ArrayList<String>`).

It's not entirely clear what `function` is supposed to do, since it's not a valid Java method, but based on the return statement I'm assuming it should return an instance of the same type as the argument `o`:

```
SomeClass function(SomeClass o, String a) { 
    // some logic 
    return some new instance of SomeClass
}
```

In order to pair elements of the two collections, you can create an `IntStream` of the indices (assuming both collections have the same number of elements).

So, assuming you have a `Collection<SomeClass>` and an `ArrayList<String>`, you can write:

```
Collection<SomeClass> first = ...
ArrayList<String> second = ...
IntStream.range(0,first.size())
         .mapToObj (i -> function(first.get(i),second.get(i)))
         ...
```

This will result in a `Stream<SomeClass>` created by applying `function` on each pair of elements. You can collect these elements into a `List<SomeClass>` or do any other required processing.

For example:

```
List<SomeClass> output = 
    IntStream.range(0,first.size())
         .mapToObj (i -> function(first.get(i),second.get(i)))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you ask about how to use `Function<T,R>` in Java 8 in map method of a certain stream.
Here a little example:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4","5");
// Both functions are equivalent, I write both to clarify the concept using lambda expression.
//Function<? super String, ? extends Integer> function = stringElement -> Integer.parseInt(stringElement);
Function<? super String, ? extends Integer> function = Integer::parseInt;
list.stream().map(function);
```